# Dog park etiquette rules

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, training, play

I'm working to compile a list of dog park etiquette rules for my clients (I'm a professional dog walker). I started a list here: [Top 10 dog park etiquette rules](http://pettium.com/top-10-dog-park-etiquette-rules) I'd love to hear if you agree/disagree with any of the rules I listed and if you feel I should add any not yet listed. Please let me know!

Here's a high-level summary of 5 I listed:

1. Pick up after your dog
2. Bring toys you don’t mind sharing
3. Keep close watch over your dog while at the park
4. Don’t allow young children to play at the dog park
5. Know your dog and the dog park’s rules

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you ask people to NOT bring toys,  this can cause dog fights.

I would encourage separating large dogs from small dogs (2 different enclosures).

I see a lot of dogs come in the clinic with some pretty bad wounds from these kinds of parks, would be nice to have a [diagram showing canine body language](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/92/bb/a6/92bba6502d06c44848a1332875e598b0.jpg).

I wouldn't recommend the retractable leash, it's very hard to control your dog with the small lead. These leashes also break easily,  are clunky and won't help at all if you need instant control of your dog (fighting with it to shorten the lead). For big dogs a [double loop leash](https://leerburg.com/Photos/TwoHandLeash_01.jpg) is wonderful,  you can keep them close and have better control.

For small dogs I would go with a regular [nylon leash](http://www.allk-9.com/images/leash_nylon_double_layer.jpg),  again better and quicker control of the situation.

Retractable leashes have their place but not in a dog park.

Other than that, looks great :)

Comment: Just make sure the diagram actually states that there are exceptions like snow dogs. We've still got problems with people who think our Huskies are aggressive permanently due to their tails alone...

Comment: same with the samoyeds we used to own. Their permanently raised tails and often open mouths (they're called the smiling dog for a reason) caused some people to think they were aggressive when all they were doing was being their own friendly selves.

Answer (score 2):

Great topic! I love dog parks and so do my dogs. Here's a few more:

- Do bring water to the dog park. All that playing is thirsty work.
- Don't bring food (people or dog food or snacks) to the dog park. It can result in conflict between dogs, and also you don't know what dietary restrictions or preferences the other dogs or dog owners have.
- Remove your dog if they are aggressive in the park. Perhaps they're just experiencing some "bad chemistry" with the crowd there, but if they're behaving aggressively, it's your responsibility to remove them.
- Have your dog's immunizations and medications up to date, and bring along the paperwork to prove it.